# How to limit network speed using tc?

Tags: linux, netfilter, trafficshaping

I have three machines: client, server and proxy. On client(1.1.1.1) I have simple script, which using wget, on server(2.2.2.1) I have apache. And on proxy machine I want to limit speed by using tc. On proxy machine I have two interfaces eth0(1.1.1.2) connected to client and eth1(2.2.2.2) connected to server.

I tried adding this rules, but they are not working:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 10mbit 
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 1mbit \
allot 1500 prio 5 bounded isolated 
tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 \
match ip dst 1.1.1.1 flowid 1:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 100mbit

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 1mbps \
   allot 1500 prio 5 bounded isolated

tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 \
   match ip dst 1.1.1.1 flowid 1:1
```